# Creating an AutoHotkey entry that ends in a colon

Tags: autohotkey

I have a weird typo that I keep making over and over, and instead of actually working on my typing skills, I want to edit my AutoHotkey script to compensate for this.

sometimes when I type the capital <kbd>I</kbd> I hit the  <kbd>:</kbd>  button and type "I:" and I want AHK to replace that string with just the letter  <kbd>I</kbd>.

I already have a similar Hotkey

::custoemr::customer

But since the string uses a colon, I am having difficulty getting it to do what I want.

Any I:deas? (See?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! It is a work around, but it works...

```
#Hotstring EndChars :
:?O:I::I
```

Anything below the line `#Hotstring EndChars :` will use the <kbd>:</kbd> as EndCharacter.

Comment: And how to disable this construction? If i want to use normal behavior after some lines below that one?

Comment: Answer to my question, how to disable this option for other hotkeys combinations: `:*?O:AA::Å` This will print Scandinavian `Å` instead of typed `AA`.

Comment: Instead of using :*?O:AA::Å, why not use :*?O:0A::Å    (zero+A). Also I think that if you set your endchar to : if only works for hotstrings below that line, so write all other hotstrings above the EndChar definition line...

Comment: To end this, you can use this #Directive after it: `#Hotstring EndChars -()[]{}:;'"/\,.?!\`n \`t` (From https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work for you it changes <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> into <kbd>I</kbd>, but it requires the <kbd>Space</kbd>.

```
:*:I`: ::I ; The `is the escape but with 3 ::: AutoHotKey still get's confused
```

Comment: How did you insert the keyboard-like characters into your answer? Im still new to Stackoverflow and learning my way around...

Comment: OK, I just tried this one, and it does work for "I: " with a space, but doesn't work if I make the typo in the middle of a word.

Comment: Updated the code and included a question mark in the beginning to make it act at any time. Oh it should now work without the space, because the : is the end character! When I type HI:JKL it turns it into HIJKL.

Comment: You can click on `edit` for an answer to see the source code (without actually submitting the edit). That's what i just did on your question.